# Function with string as return type in C Error: cannot access at memory ''

Tags: c

I want to program a function that gives me a string as return type. With this code I always get the Error: 'word' cannot access the memory at '0x63736e41'.

Main:

```
FILE *datei;
datei = fopen("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\dictionary.txt", "r");

char *word = getRandomWord(datei);
```

Function:

```
char* getRandomWord(FILE *datei)
{
    int length = fsize("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\dictionary.txt"); //Get lenght of file
    srand(time(NULL));
    int randIndex = rand() % length+1; //Random number between 0 and the length of the file

    char *cTest = malloc(20);

    fseek(datei, randIndex, SEEK_SET); //I want to read only one random line from the file
    fscanf(datei, "%s\0", &cTest);
    fscanf(datei, "%s\0", &cTest);

    return cTest;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have multiple problems with the code you show.

The most serious and the probable cause of your crash is that you pass a pointer *to the pointer* when you use the address-of operator `&` in `&cTest`.

Remember that the `scanf` format `%s` expects an argument of type `char *`. When you do `&cTest` you get a value of type `char **`, which is very wrong and will lead to *undefined behavior* (and likely crashes).

The simple solution is to just pass `cTest` as it is, since it's already the correct type:

```
fscanf(datei, "%19s", cTest);
```

---

Note that in my shown call to `fscanf` I specified a field-width of `19`, that's so the `fscanf` function will not read to much and write out of bounds of your allocated memory.

I also do not have the string-terminator `\0` in the format string, it isn't needed and the `fscanf` function will just see it as the end of the format string.

And are you sure you want to call `fscanf` *twice*, with the same `cTest` destination? The second call will overwrite the contents you read with the first call (making you lose the string read by the first call).

You seek to a random position in the file. There's no guarantee that it will be the start of a word. There not even a guarantee that it will be somewhere *in* the file: Your calculation could return a position one beyond the end of the file.

And lastly, talking about the randomness: On any modern PC-like system the `time(NULL)` call will return an integer with the number of seconds since an epoch. That means if you call your function twice (or more) within a single second, then each call will set the same seed, making `rand()` return the exact same value. So each of those calls to your function will cause it to read the exact same data. Call `srand` only *once* at the beginning of your program.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I seek to a random point in the file, then I call fscanf twice. The first fscanf will read to the end of the line, the second will read the whole next line. This way I have a whole line in the string cTest. (I couldnt find a better way to do it).

Comment: @Ruberduck Then there's yet *another* problem, because `%s` reads ***space delimited words***, not lines. If you want to read lines use e.g. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets).